# How do I efficiently generate CPAN links for SO answers?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

There are a couple of different ways to provide URLs for CPAN modules.

The Best Practice ([very well documented in this Meta SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/how-should-i-link-to-cpan-modules-in-answers/17106#17106)) is to generate a link using `http://search.cpan.org/perldoc` URL, as follows:

- Desired Module: `Rose::HTML::Form::Field`
- URL to use:     `http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rose::HTML::Form::Field`
- Resulting Link: [`Rose::HTML::Form::Field`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rose::HTML::Form::Field)

Unfortunately, there is a problem with following that Best Practice consistently, at least in the usual mode I operate in when answering SO `[Perl]` tag questions; which for me is:

- Googling for the module name
- Follow the (usually correct) link to the module's POD
- Confirm whatever is needed in the POD and/or copy/paste short examples from Synopsis if needed
- Place the link to the module into the answer **by copying and pasting the URL of the POD I opened**.
- *PROBLEM*: cpan.org always automatically re-directs the "canonical" version-independent URL shown above into a version-and-author-specific URL: http://search.cpan.org/~jsiracusa/Rose-HTML-Objects-0.611/lib/Rose/HTML/Form/Field.pm
  Therefore, the URL I copy/paste into the link in my answer is a bad one, not the canonical one.

I can use the three obvious solutions:

1. Let cjm edit the answer afterwards with the correct URL. No headache for my lazy head and [Gold Copy Editor Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) for cjm :)
2. Memorize the damn cpan.org's search URL prefix and type it every time. This is not an efficient use of either memory or time IMHO.
3. Use `p3rl.org` Perl resource re-director: http://p3rl.org/Rose::HTML::Form::Field

   This is a lot easier than #2 as far as effort level, but my concern is "what happens if p3rl.org disappears?". It's also not quite copy/paste and thus subject to typos.

**QUESTION**

*Are there other approaches I can use that are better?* I was thinking of some kind of FireFox or greasemonkey add-on that would generate a link. The way I see this would be to piggyback on Markdown editor and perhaps add an icon for "Link to Perl resource" in addition to usual "Make a generic URL" one

Comment: Belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: @Paul - Don't think so since I think the correct answer may be programmatic (e.g. a script)

Comment: This was already asked (and answered) on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/how-should-i-link-to-cpan-modules-in-answers

Comment: @Ether - please read carefully. I specifically linked to that question, which answered "how to form a URL", and my question was "how do I **efficiently** form the URL that the linked question recommends (e.g. with 1/2 clicks/keystrokes).

Comment: I actually did see that you already referenced that question. I was trying to say that this question didn't ask anything extra on top of that one (IMHO).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org/~jsiracusa/Rose-HTML-Objects-0.611/lib/Rose/HTML/Form/Field.pm has a link marked "permalink" in the top right. Right click on it, and copy link location instead of going to the address bar.

Comment: Hmm... looks like I was over-complicating things and CPAN already has an answer I just didn't notice. +1

Comment: It took me a long time to spot it too

Comment: That's the way I do it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hi, as the owner and maintainer of p3rl.org, I have no intention of letting it disappear. :)

If you have specific questions or concerns, please contact me directly.

Comment: @Juerd - First - Good job! I really appreciate the resource! Second - no concerns specific to your website - merely the expectation that all good things in life have a chance to disappear. Heck, even ones run and supported by Google do (e.g. Google Notebook).

Answer (score 1):

As an example, were I to link to Dist::Zilla, I'd use:

- to link to the whole dist, http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla/
- to link to a specific module POD inside that dist, http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/MetaJSON.pm
- for a binary's pod, http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla/bin/dzil
- for a POD-only module, http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook.pod

The added value is that it's not tied to a specific version release.

Comment: For a specific module POD, http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MetaJSON  or http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MetaJSON are equivalent to your suggestion.

Comment: Most of those assume that the files you link to will always be in the distribution in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to link to the distribution rather than the documentation of one module within the distribution. The top-level distribution page leads to all of the other links for the distribution. I think you're being a bit weasly in your assertion about best practices by ignoring the first advice given in the answer to that Meta post.

I don't see what's so hard about making the link or remembering CPAN Search's prefix.

Comment: Sorry but I see the linked best practices as two SEPARATE advices for two SEPARATE situations - one for when you need to link to a distribution, one when you need to link to specific module's POD. Usually when I answer a question, the context is such that a link to module's POD is more useful. As far as "what's so hard" - it's harder than NOT to. In my line of work people generally care about programmatic solutions to think that otherwise require rote memorization and manual typing where it's not needed, so that's the way I usually view the issues.

Comment: BTW, there's a similar permalink in the upper right corner of the dist page, for people who prefer linking to that.

Comment: There's no guarantee that linking directly into a particular file in a distro will be a stable link.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the "efficiently", I try to always test any links in my posts' previews, even if I just copy and pasted them from a location bar.